# Can we change coordinates to the Schwarzschild metric and interpret the result as the field corresponding to different matter distributions?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, coordinate-systems, mass-energy, density

The Schwarzschild metric is the simplest solution to Einstein field equations. It describes the gravitational field around a static object with spherical symmetry.

Perhaps a change in space coordinates could help compute the solutions for a more general (non-symmetric) mass distribution? For example, a scale change for the different space axes could be interpreted as the description of an ellipsoidal type of object, and so on.

Comment: Note that any change in coordinates that does not change the underlying metric is entirely allowed by GR, but does not correspond to any physically different situation. GR is a theory about the shape of the metric, not its coordinates.

Comment: See [Scholarpedia, 9(10):31791](https://bit.ly/3Q1SmFH): *"it was soon noticed that the Kerr solution could also be found by applying an unusual complex coordinate transformation to the Schwarzschild metric. Hence, it seemed likely that a transformation r→r+i a cos θ could take the Schwarzschild to the Kerr metric; with a few subtleties, this was seen to be true. [...] Hence, Schwarzschild can be associated to Reissner-Nordström and likewise Kerr to Kerr-Newman; once the link between Schwarzschild and Kerr is established, it is clear that it can be extended to the charged setting"*, etc.